# IS a set $X$ consisting of all finite subsets of $\Omega$ and their complements will be a $\sigma-$ algebra??

Tags: measure-theory

If $\Omega$ is an infinite set. A set $X$ consists of all finite subsets of $\Omega$ and their complements. Can we say $X$ is a $\sigma-$algebra??

I am able to verify the two properties of a $\sigma-$algebra i,e. 
$1. \emptyset \in X$ as $\emptyset$ is an finite set 
$2.$ $\forall$ $E_i\in$ $X$, $E_i^ c\in X$ (given)

I am not able to understand how to check  the 3rd property of $\sigma-$algebra i,e. 
$3.$ $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$ $\in$ $X$

help me, i am new to this course.

Comment: The property 3. states that any countably infinite family of measurable sets has a measurable union. If you take countably infinitely many finite sets, you union them and obtain an infinite set (in general).

Comment: This is an algebra but not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can you please elaborate, how??

Comment: You only have to check finite unions or intersections for algebras. That’s it’s not a $\sigma$-algebra has already been answered.

Answer (score 5):

This is because that third property is not true.

Consider, for instance, $\Omega := \Bbb N$ and let $E_i := \{2i\}$. Clearly, $E_i \in X$. However, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$ is the even, positive integers. This is not finite. Its complement, the odd positive integers, also is not finite, so the union can't be in $X$.